# Как сделать боту приветствие нового участника в группе?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, python-3.8

Здраствуйте, вот такая ситуация. Как сделать боту приветствие, я попробовал что-то накуралесить, получилось так, что при каждом новом участнике в группе, бот тегает меня, а не нового участника.

Вот код

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def new_member(message):
    name = message.from_user.username
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Добро пожаловать, @{name}!")
```

я взял код с другого поста, изначально было написано

```
name = message.new_chat_member.first_name
```

но выходила ошибка

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'first_name'
```

Comment: Приведите ваш код, чтобы было что исправлять. Исправьте заголовок так, чтобы в нём был вопрос, а не утверждение.

Comment: Исправил, я недавно тут, могу накосячить, так сойдет?

Comment: Сойдёт. Python, telebot и прочее такое надо писать в тегах, а не в тексте, я поправил

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш `content_type` должен быть `new_chat_members`:

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
def new_member(message):
    name = message.new_chat_members[0].first_name 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Добро пожаловать, @{name}!")
```

Comment: Он выдает ошибку, в описании поста , в конце написано, какая ошибка

Comment: Какую конкретно ошибку?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'first_name'

Comment: Попробуйте задампить, `print(message.new_chat_members)`, что там лежит?

Comment: Извини, я не понимаю ваш слэнг, можно конкретно, что надо сделать?

Comment: Перед `name = message.new_chat_member.first_name` вставьте `print(message.new_chat_members)`. Если Вы запускаете бота в консоли, то в ней будет выведено содержимое message.new_chat_members

Comment: Обновил код ответа, попробуйте сейчас

Comment: Все, спасибо огромное) Бот заработал, теперь он приветствует)